# Export/Dump database in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I dump a database in neo4j?
I have tried to follow the recommendations on the website and nothing works.

Comment: what doesn't work? are you using Neo4j Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

In Neo4j Desktop 1.3.11 you can click on the dot dot dot in the top right (database must be stopped first), and choose the option *Dump* (my test named the file movie-database-neo4j-2020-12-11T184026.dump)

[image]

Note:  You will probably have to search your disk (for *.dump) to find where the files drop, on Macintosh I found them in an unexpected folder location, they were placed with the Project instead of in the database's dump folder whereI expected them to fall out.

I found my dumps over in here
[image]

I tried changing the config and created data/dumps/ folder in the database area but it still sends them to the project area.  YMMV